# PHP http request method that is compatiable with all php 5.2 installs

Tags: php

Is curl on most php installs for windows, Mac, and Linux.

I know it is an extension and doesn't have to be enabled.

I am making soap requests and need the most used method to make these requests.

Answer (score 1):

For SOAP requests, use the SoapClient--it should be enabled.  Run on the commandline `php -m` and `soap` should show up in the list of modules.  For other web requests, use the pear library HTTP_Request2 (http://pear.php.net/package/HTTP_Request2/redirected).  It can be pulled down via pear or manually and dumped into your libraries.  No compiling or changing the php install required.